# Can anyone help with a formula to pull an email address from a text string in a standard field?

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to pull an email address from a text string in the standard "Description" field on Case object.

The below formula is correctly pulling everything AFTER the "@" symbol in the email address, (for example "@sample.com").I cannot get it to pull the first part of the email address.

Here is the formula I am using

```
SUBSTITUTE( Description ,RIGHT(Description, FIND("@",Description))+ LEFT(Description, FIND("@",Description)), NULL)
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a character that marks the beginning of the email string? If not, is there a fixed size to these emails? Or, is there a space before the email string begins?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this via a formula field.  You will have to do it with a trigger.

I tried to get this working with just Pattern and Matcher but was having issues.  You can use this (it's pretty inefficient but it works)

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update) {
    for (Case c: Trigger.new) {
        if (c.Description != null) {
            Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile('(?i)^([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4})$');
            Boolean foundEmailMatch = false;

            for (String bit: c.Description.split(' ')) {
                Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(bit);
                if (emailMatcher.matches()) {
                    foundEmailMatch = true;
                    c.Description_Email__c = bit;
                }
            }

            if (!foundEmailMatch) {
                c.Description_Email__c = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that the reason your formula doesn't work is because it's written in reverse. You have it written as `RIGHT + LEFT` when it needs to be written as `LEFT + RIGHT`. It worked for me when I essentially reversed what you had as follows:

```
SUBSTITUTE( Description ,LEFT(Description, FIND("@",Description)) + RIGHT(Description, FIND("@",Description)), NULL)
```